# How do I get lsof to stop complaining when testing for a socket?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, lsof

I need to test whether any process is listening on a specific socket; `fuser` does not exist on the target system but `lsof` does. I run this command:

```bsh
lsof -tU /path/to/socket
```

It lists the PID of the listener, which is great but `lsof` exits with a status of `1`. I change the command to see what's wrong:

```bsh
lsof -tUV /path/to/socket
```

It again lists the PID but also adds this:

> lsof: no file use located: /path/to/socket

Is there any way to suppress this extra check of 'file use' so that it exits with `0` when it *does* find listeners on the socket? I've looked through the man page but can't find what I'm after. I'd like to use it sensibly like this:

```bsh
sock=/path/to/socket
if [[ ! -S $sock ]] || ! lsof -tU $sock &>/dev/null; then
    # task to activate socket listener
fi
```

Comment: @user431397 CentOS. So do you know of an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on a system with a recent version of `ss` (like that from `iproute2-ss190107` on Debian 10), you can use `ss` instead of `lsof`:

```
sock=/path/to/socket
ino=$(stat -c 'ino:%i' "$sock") && ss -elx | grep -w "$ino"

sock=/path/to/socket
if ino=$(stat -c 'ino:%i' "$sock") && ss -elx | grep -qw "$ino"
then
   # yeah, somebody's listening on $sock
fi
```

There are two important things to notice here:

1. The real address of a Unix socket is the `device,inode` number tuple, **not the pathname**. If a socket file is *moved*, whichever server was listening on it will be accessible via the new path. If a socket file is *removed*, another server can listen on the same path (that's why the directory permissions of a Unix socket are important, security-wise). `lsof` isn't able to cope with that, and may return incomplete / incorrect data.
2. `ss` is itself buggy, and because the `unix_diag` netlink interface `ss` is using returns the device number in the format internally used by the Linux kernel, but `ss` assumes that it's in the format used by system calls interfaces like `stat(2)`, the `dev:` entry in the `ss -elx` output above will be manged. However, de-mangling it may be unwise, because one day they may just decide to fix it. So, the only course of action is to treat `dev:` as pure garbage, and live with the risk of having two socket files with the same inode, but on different filesystems, **which the test above is not able to handle**.

---

If all of the above doesn't matter for you, you can do the same lousy thing `lsof` does (matching on the path the socket was first bound to), with:

```
sock=/path/to/socket
ss -elx | grep " $sock "
```

which should also work on older systems like Centos 7. At least this does have the advantage of only listing the *listening* sockets ;-)

Comment: I arrived at the same conclusion (`ss | grep`) before I came back to share, saw your comment, was relieved, went to post my answer, got interrupted, then saw you had done so already. I'll mark yours as answer anyway for the detail.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was this:

```bsh
if ! [[ -S $SSH_AUTH_SOCK && -n "`ss -xa 2>/dev/null | grep -F $SSH_AUTH_SOCK 2>/dev/null`" ]]; then
    # task to activate socket listener
fi
```

Ugly but functional.